# aura:interation Field Order

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-iteration

I'm developing a component to add multiple items (in this example debts). When a new debt is added I need the fields to display like so:

[image]

At the moment the fields display like this:

[image]

Here is my component code:

```
<aura:component controller="FFNewController" 
            implements="force:appHostable,
                        force:hasRecordId,
                        force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,
                        flexipage:availableForRecordHome,
                        lightning:actionOverride" 
            access="global">

<aura:attribute name="DebtsType" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="MonthlyRepaymentAmount" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="DebtCounter" type="Integer" default="1"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<div style="background-color: white">

    <div class="slds-grid 
                slds-gutters">

        <div class="slds-col">

            <!-- Adds Debt Type field-->
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.DebtsType}" var="DebtType">
                <lightning:select                       
                                  aura:id="{!DebtType.id}"
                                  value="{!DebtType.value}"
                                  label="{!DebtType.label}"
                                  >

                    <option value="Car lease (HP)">Car lease (HP)</option>
                    <option value="Car lease (PCP)">Car lease (PCP)</option>

                </lightning:select>
            </aura:iteration>

            <!-- Adds Monthly Repayment Amount field-->
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.MonthlyRepaymentAmount}" var="MonthlyRepaymentAmount">                     
                <lightning:input                     
                                 aura:id="{!MonthlyRepaymentAmount.id}"
                                 value="{!MonthlyRepaymentAmount.value}"
                                 label="{!MonthlyRepaymentAmount.label}"
                                 type="number"
                                 formatter="currency" 
                                 />
            </aura:iteration>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="slds-col
                slds-size_6-of-12">

    </div>



    <div class="slds-grid 
                slds-gutters">

        <div class="slds-col
                    slds-size_6-of-12">

            <!-- Add button -->
            <lightning:button onclick="{!c.addDebt}" 
                              label="Add Debt" 
                              variant="brand" 
                              name="addDebt" 
                              value="{!v.DebtCounter}"/> 

            <!-- Remove button -->
            <aura:if isTrue="{!greaterthan(v.DebtCounter, 1)}">
                <lightning:button onclick="{!c.removeDebt}" 
                                  label="Remove Debt" 
                                  variant="brand" 
                                  name="removeDebt" 
                                  value="{!v.DebtCounter}"/>

            </aura:if>

        </div>

        <div class="slds-col
                    slds-size_6-of-12">

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and any questions please dont hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need use only one  aura:iteration

```
 <!-- Adds Debt Type field-->
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.DebtsType}" var="DebtType">
            <lightning:select                       
                              aura:id="{!DebtType.Debtid}"
                              value="{!DebtType.Debtvalue}"
                              label="{!DebtType.Debtlabel}"
                              >
                <option value="Car lease (HP)">Car lease (HP)</option>
                <option value="Car lease (PCP)">Car lease (PCP)</option>
            </lightning:select>
             <lightning:input                     
                             aura:id="{!DebtType.Monthlyid}"
                             value="{!DebtType.Monthlyvalue}"
                             label="{!DebtType.Monthlylabel}"
                             type="number"
                             formatter="currency" 
                             />

        </aura:iteration>
```

Also add new variable in DebtsType as i use above example

Comment: Hi Rijwan, thats perfect, Thanks for your quick reply!